# Joining attributes from both sides of a line

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, attribute-joins

I have a layer with street segments that I would like to join with a building + population layer. Desired result: The segment contains population data. Nearest neighbor (NNjoin) finds the closest building and adds its population to the attribute table. Issue: there are buildings on both sides of the segment.
Is there a way I can join attributes from several buildings (within a radius, for example) to the segment, adding their values together?
I use QGIS and GRASS GIS. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried with attributes by nearest, but that does not seem to solve the issue of adding the population data together and placing it on the line. I am trying to go the other way now. I have given each building the same id as the nearest segment. 
Now I need to find a clever way to add the values for each id and join it back to the segment.

Answer (score 1):

[image]I found one solution:

1. Join nearest neighbor, but segment to building (each building looking for the closest segment).
2. Use Group Stats Plugin to sum the population for each join_id.
3. Export the result as cvs
4. Import into QGIS as delimited text layer (as attribute table)
5. Join the values to the segments.